# TSLint Config in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

I'm trying to configure the max line length (among other settings) for TS Lint in VS code but no matter what changes I make it doesn't 'take'.

So, the first strange thing is that VS code's TS Lint error for max line length says I've exceeded the 140 character limit but in the various config files I've found it only ever mentions 120 characters as the default.

I've changed this to 200 characters, disabled / enabled the extension but still get the 140 character warning. Does anyone know where and how to configure this setting? The documentation online is clear enough but I don't appear to have a tslint.json file and within the node_modules => tslint => lib => rules folder the setting is 120 and changing it makes no difference.

Comment: Is your question regarding the [tslint package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint) or the corresponding [vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint)?

Comment: It's regarding the VS Code extension but perhaps the answer applies to the package as well? I'm unfamiliar with TSLint (only having used it through VS Code) so maybe need to clarify in my question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Edit 2020-09-30

Microsoft deprectaded the [old plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) and released a newer, completely rewritten version with additional features [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin).

For the new plugin the setting `"tslint.enable": true` does not exists and is not needed anymore.

## Original Answer

You need to create a `tslint.json` (in your workspace root) and set something like this to disable the maximum line length:

```json
{    
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:recommended"
    ],
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {
        "max-line-length": [false]
    },
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

Furthermore, ensure that the following options are set in the in the vscode user settings (`settings.json`):

```json
"tslint.configFile": "./path/to/tslint/relative/from/workspaceroot/tslint.json",
"tslint.enable": true
```

The `tslint.configFile` option can be empty if the file is in the root directory of your workspace.
Further rules can be found [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/).

Comment: Perfect thank you! Is it just me or is this not clear in the documentation?

Comment: Have you found the [tslint homepage](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/)? When you follow the Quickstart and run `tslint --init` helps you to create your first inital `tslint.json` file.

Comment: Thanks,  this is the link the VS code brings you to, which is less clear. https://github.com/palantir/tslint but I should have spent longer looking.

Comment: `tslint.enable` seems no longer to exist as a setttings property (Sept 2020, vscode 1.48.2)

Comment: You are right this setting only exists on the [deprecated version](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) of the plugin