# How to configure tsline in settings.json?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I am using visual studio code

When i search for settings.json file it looks like this

```
{
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {},
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [
    
    ]
}
```

how can i configure my vs code so every time when i format my document It will use my tsline rules

for prettier i already found answer for that
reference here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640469/how-do-you-determine-which-formatter-is-being-used-for-vs-code`

but what should be the value for tsline on `editor.defaultFormatter`
so it will use tslint ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd like to mention that TSLint has been deprecated and all the functionality added/replaced in ESLint and I recommend you use that.
Here's an article how to migrate for TSLint to ESLint (https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint#typescript-eslint)

1. Download and install ESLint extension
2. Once you've downloaded the extension, hit gear icon to go into the **Extension Settings**
3. In **Extension Settings** you will see **Eslint > Format: Enable** that needs to be checked (image attached below).
   [image]

Comment: I know it is depricated but i followed the project where it is already used, and for now I need to use tslint

Comment: @Andrej12345 in this case, try something like this, I think it answers your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744766/tslint-config-in-vs-code

long story short:

- you need tslint.json with configuration

- settings json pointing at tslint.json file with tslint enabled 

"tslint.configFile": "./path/to/tslint/relative/from/workspaceroot/tslint.json",

"tslint.enable": true